# How to define and import choice fields?

Tags: django

How can I define choice field in models. When I tried below code, I'm getting

> errorNameError: name 'GENDER_CHOICES' is not defined.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import 

class Userprofile(models.Model):
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=GENDER_CHOICES, 
      blank=True)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
  )
```

Comment: `GENDER_CHOICES` needs to be defined *before* the `gender` field

Comment: k any import is required.

Comment: How to define in model forms?

Answer (score 1):

This is not Django specific, but a Python thing: you need to define (or import) variables before you can use them; in this case the tuple `GENDER_CHOICES` is not defined yet when you try to use it.

Here is the improved code:

```
from django.db import models

class Userprofile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        blank=True)
```

Comment: How to define in model forms?